# Under what circumstance might your email not make to your intended recipient?

Tags: email, attacks, spoofing

I'm asking because it's one thing to eavesdrop on someone's email, but it's another thing to prevent your email from getting to your recipient. For example, I sent an email to a colleague and he and I exchanged several back and forth emails about the nature of our confidential project.  I later discovered that my colleague never received my email and therefore was not the person responding to my email.  So what exactly happened here?  Did someone get into my email server, or my colleague's email server?  I'm trying to figure out how someone can physically block an email from getting through.

Answer (score 2):

Email is sent over SMTP.  Normally speaking your email client sends the message to a configured SMTP server.  That server then uses DNS to resolve the MX (mail exchanger) record for the destination domain (the part after the @ sign).  It then sends the message on to that server.

If your SMTP server or the DNS it uses were compromised it could send to a malicious MX that allows an interloper to not only read the message, but prevent its delivery to your intended recipient.

The attacker forging a reply is trivial if the sender's domain (your colleague's domain) does not have SPF (Sender Protection Framework) implemented.  In that case an attacker can send email as your colleague and it will likely get through.

You should be able to determine a lot by looking at the raw email source if your email client allows this.  The headers provide a certain amount of information about where your mail server received the attacker's messages from.  Comparing the headers on your sent mail to those on the received messages may provide insight as well.

These headers won't track a somewhat clever attacker because they will mask, forge or omit the **Received** headers on their side.  The only information you can trust is the very last **Received** header and that is only true if your email server is configured properly and not compromised by the attacker.  Unfortunately open SMTP relays exist making it very easy for an attacker to bounce email through and drop all meaningful tracking.

Assuming you have usable **Received** headers you may be able to reconstruct a real path to your attacker and unmask them.  It will certainly identify opportunities for implementing proper SPF on both domains and spam filtering that drops emails that fail SPF verification.

Comment: What do you mean when you write, "The only information you can trust is the very last Received header and that is only true if your email server is configured properly and not compromised by the attacker. Unfortunately open SMTP relays exist making it very easy for an attacker to bounce email through and drop all meaningful tracking."  Are you saying that the attacker can mask everything in the header-- even the Received part?  How would I know if my my server has been compromised?

Comment: I mean that there are many **Received** headers and only the last one (controlled by your email server), can be trusted in any way.  The others are easily dropped or forged by malicious SMTP servers along the way.

Comment: The last one, the one all the way on the bottom, can't be spoofed?  But if they have my contacts info, what's to say that my server hasn't been compromised?